# Inequality with the supremum

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove the following statement for $A\subset \mathbb{R},~\epsilon>0$ with $A$ bounded above:

$\sup(A)-\epsilon<a\leq\sup(A)$, for some $a \in A$

I have tried dividing it into two cases.

Case 1: $\sup(A)\in A$. Then take $a=\sup(A)$ and we are done.

Case 2: $\sup(A)\notin A$. I tried to formalise the idea that if we started writing down elements of $A$ in increasing order, then the maximum element of these lists must tend to $\sup(A)$. This is because if it didn't, then there would be some element at which we would have to stop before we got as close as we wanted to $\sup(A)$. This element would be the least upper bound, but $\sup(A)\notin A $ which is a contradiction. Hence there exists $\epsilon$ such that $|a_n-\sup(A)|<\epsilon$ for some $n$ and the result follows.

Is this proof valid? Are there any better ones?

Thanks.

Comment: By definition of $\sup(A)$, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $\sup(A)-\epsilon < a$ (and of course, $a\leq \sup(A)$).

Comment: In any case, observe that $\sup A-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $A$, so the statement follows without distinguishing cases  (assuming $\sup A$ has been defined has the least upper bound of $A$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no such $a$, then $\sup(A) - \epsilon$ is a new *l.u.b.*, contradiction.